# How to query a collection of line segments to see if a given line segment intersects any of them

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, plane-geometry

I have a collection of `n` 2D line segments in the plane, some non-orthogonal and possibly intersecting, which I am allowed to pre-process.  I would like to be able to query to see if a given line segment (not in the collection) intersects any of the segments in the collection.  Ideally I would like to know the number of intersections as well.  How can this be done in `o(n)`?

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 3 in [this paper of Chazelle](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/ReportingCountingSegIntersect.pdf) says: given $n$ line segments and $O(n^2)$ preprocessing time, you can find all intersections between those and another line segment in $O(\log n+t)$ time where $t$ is the number of intersections.

This isn't exactly what you're after (in the case where there are many intersections it will not take time $o(n)$; obviously nothing that actually reports the intersections could, but perhaps something that merely determines whether there are any could) but it might be near enough for your application.

Hmm, actually we can adapt this to solve the easier version of your problem (i.e., without counting) too, though I make no claim it's anything like optimal even if Chazelle's algorithm is optimal for the problem he's solving. Take your $n$ line segments, divide them into (say) $\sqrt n$ groups of size $\sqrt n$, preprocess them separately, and when a new line segment comes along apply Chazelle's procedure to the groups one at a time. Stop as soon as you find any intersection. This never takes longer than $O(\sqrt n \log n)$.

I suspect (but have made no attempt to check) that actually Chazelle's argument solves the easier version of your problem in time $O(\log n)$ if you just make it stop as soon as it finds any intersection.

What about the harder version (counting)? Chazelle's paper has a brief section about counting, but considers only the question of counting all the intersections among $n$ line segments, which he can do in time $O(n^{1.695})$. I don't know (and have made no attempt to check) whether his technique can be adapted to count intersections in your scenario in time $o(n)$, but it might be worth a look.

That paper is from 1986. Some of the results in it have been improved since then. I don't know whether any of those improvements lead to better solutions to either version of your problem. (The ones I found with a quick search don't look as if they do.)

Comment: I understood the OP to be interested in the number of intersections a line segment makes with line segments in the set, and not in the number of intersections between the line segments in the set. Your answer seems to indicate you disagree?

Comment: I don't disagree at all; I'm sorry that what I wrote was unclear enough to give that impression.

Comment: The main subject of Chazelle's paper is (not OP's question but) how to find all intersections among n given segments. But one byproduct of that work is his theorem 3, which comes close to doing what OP wants and may be adaptable to do exactly what OP wants. Chazelle's paper also has a section specifically about counting, but (in line with Chazelle's main concern in the paper) it's again not about OP's question but about counting all intersections among n segments. I mentioned it only because it's possible that a close look would find a way to use it for OP's question.

Comment: Thanks for this paper!  I will read it and determine if I can use it, but yeah I need to be able to solve the non-counting version in O(log n).  However O(n^2) preprocessing time is rather heavy.  Surely there must be an O(n log n) way to do it.

Comment: I might have read your answer wrong (me fail English often). Anyway, the $O(n)$ (counting) solution seems trivial to me, since checking whether two line segments intersect is an $O(1)$ operation. (If line segments are specified as having endpoints $(x, y)$ and $(x + x_\Delta , y + y_\Delta)$, then you need six multiplications, five subtractions, and six comparisons to check if two 2D line segments intersect, without any prior calculations. To count which $N$ line segments a line segment intersects, you need at most $6 N$ multiplications, $5 N$ subtractions, and $6 N$ comparisons.)

Comment: I have not yet read the Chazelle paper, but obviously $O(log(n) + k)$ for $n$ line segments in the collection and $k$ intersections total, is better than $O(n)$ (unless $k \approx n$). However, if the line segments are short, then splitting the plane into a regular rectangular grid, and listing the line segments that intersect a given cell for each cell, may be a viable alternative with $\approx O(n m)$ time in preparation work, where $m$ is the average number of cells each line segment spans; the check/counting is $\approx O(m l)$, with $l$ number of segments intersecting each cell.

Comment: It seems the Chazelle paper will not serve my purposes, as Theorem 3 concerns n lines, not n line segments...

Comment: Hmmm. Although it says "lines" I can't help thinking it surely must mean "line segments" since everything else in the paper is concerned with line segments, including in particular the things Theorem 3 is allegedly a consequence of.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Chazelle didn't see fit to go into a bit more detail about how theorem 3 follows from lemmas 1 and 2...